# How to partially update Apollo client cache after fetching GraphQL query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jsx, apollo

I have massive query, which looks like this: https://pastebin.com/pMp4iNDc.

I have made also second query, which task would be to fetch only needed fields and update them in apollo cache, the query looks like that:

```
export const SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_FREE_TIME_LEFT = gql(`query GetFreeTimeLeft {
  teleport {
    enteredZoneData {
      timeToFreeTry
      positionPrice {
        currency
        amount
      }
    }
  }
}
`);
```

**So the main idea is that when the second query data is fetched it should update the cache which is coming from the first query.**

My plan currently is to pass callback function to timer component, and execute the callback after time become zero.

Example:

```
const TeleportGrid = () => {
    const eventData = useApolloClient().cache.readQuery({query: SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_DATA}).teleport;
    const [fetchNewTime] = useLazyQuery(SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_FREE_TIME_LEFT);

    return (
        <TimerElement timerId={"counterNextFreeTry"} translation={__('event_teleport_position_time_until_free_try')} time={eventData.enteredZoneData.timeToFreeTry} callback={() => {
        return fetchNewTime();
    }}
    />
    );
}
```

What I have tried till now ?

- Use onComplete option from useLazyQuery and manually do writeQuery to update the cache
- Use promise chain after fetchNewTime() and manually do writeQuery to update the cache

I haven't tried the useMutation because in this case we are not really mutating anything we are getting new data and updating cache.

```
Thanks for any advices in advance !
Have an awesome day <3
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Apollo's cache, but according to the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/overview), normalized data should update itself in the cache. In your case, this does not happen.

- Try setting `fetchPolicy: network-only`;
- If that doesn't work, try [tweaking](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-cache-ids) your cache;
- You can also directly use `cache.modify` in `onCompleted()` with `fetchPolicy: no-cache`;

```
const TeleportGrid = () => {
  const {cache} = useApolloClient();
  const eventData = cache.readQuery({query: SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_DATA}).teleport;
  const [fetchNewTime] = useLazyQuery(SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_FREE_TIME_LEFT, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      cache.modify(...modify logic)
    }
  });

  return ...;
}
```

PS. Let me remind you that queries have option `pollInterval`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for suggestions !
1. I do need cache so network-only is not an option
2. Will work only if we call the same request, which we don't wanna do, because back end work is alot, we want to get only 3 fields, not the whole query.
3. Again, we do need cache.
For the ps: yep there is pollInterval but again it will refetch the big query, which is alot back end work, we do need only 3 rows, which are described in second query 
Thanks once again <3

Comment: Regarding option 3, you didn’t understand a bit, when requesting “SCHEMA_TELEPORT_GET_FREE_TIME_LEFT”, you don’t need to cache this request, but you need to update an existing cache, which can be done using “cache.modify” when calling "onСomplete"

Comment: Regarding point 1, this means that the application will request data from the network with each request and update the cache. Try to use it in useLazyQuery

Comment: You are freaking right, big missundestanding from my side, I will try later again and will return here, thank you!